# Rogue text output on my Search Page: "onContentSearch"

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code, search

I'm getting some odd output on my Search Page

onContentSearch appears above the Page Title.

http://compaci.org/en/search?searchword=partner&searchphrase=all

I'm stumped, any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that function is defined at /plugins/search/content/content.php -> line 32 - have a look to see if anything is unusual there.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that onContentSearch is written in echo or print_r , you can search the string in code to detect it in search plugin or component used on your site, can check the article content if any is set on this page from admin panel and also check the index file of your template.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem couldn't find solution on other websites, so fixed it myself.

In my case solution was to remove `onContentSearch` on first line in the file:

> public_html/plugins/search/fieldsattachmentadvanced/fieldsattachmentadvanced.php

Probably the developer put it there by mistake. :)